I'm trying to use the CreateTableOne package to run statistical tests on a dataframe and R is not outputting any result when running the code
library(readxl)
library(tableone)
zipstats <- read_excel("zipstats.xlsx", sheet = 1)
head(zipstats)
varstofactor <- c("Zip_Code","Expected_Mortality_Change 20_21", "White_Alone", "Black", "Hispanic",
"Asian_alone", "Other", "Income_Quartile")
zipstats[varstofactor] <- lapply(zipstats[varstofactor], factor)
dput(names(zipstats))
vars <- c("Zip_Code","Expected_Mortality_Change 20_21", "White_Alone", "Black", "Hispanic",
"Asian_alone", "Other", "Income_Quartile")
tableOne <- CreateTableOne(vars = vars, strata = "Income_Quartile", data = zipstats)
tableOne
#Expected output of statistical tests but R wont result

A sample zipstats.xlsx or the output of dput(zipstats) is required to reproduce the problem.
